# Angular 5 Observable mapping to Json array

Tags: json, angular, mapping

My backend return this :

```
{
    "FirstResponse": [
        {
            "MyField1": "AAA",
            "MyField2": "AAAAAAA"
        },
        {
            "MyField1": "BBB",
            "MyField2": "BBBBBBB"
        },
        {
            "MyField1": "CCC",
            "MyField2": "CCCCC"
        }
    ],
    "SecondResponse": [
        {
            "FirstName": "FirstNameA",
            "LastName": "LastNameA"
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "FirstNameB",
            "LastName": "LastNameB"
        }
    ]   
}
```

I'd like map `FirstReponse` to a variable and `SecondResponse` to another variable.

How can I adapt the code below ?

```
search(): Observable<any> {
  let apiURL = `......`;
  return this.http.get(apiURL) 
      .map(res => res.json())
}
```

Update : Excepted result
In one variable this :

```
[
    {
        "MyField1": "AAA",
        "MyField2": "AAAAAAA"
    },  
    {
        "MyField1": "BBB",
        "MyField2": "BBBBBBB"
    },
    {
        "MyField1": "CCC",
        "MyField2": "CCCCC"
    }
]
```

In a second :

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "FirstNameA",
        "LastName": "LastNameA"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "FirstNameB",
        "LastName": "LastNameB"
    }
]
```

Comment: I would say, your backend should simply return the values that you actually want to get. Or is it important to you that the data looks like in your example?

Comment: What is exact result that you wanna get (give proper json) ?

Comment: Did you try this ? : `search(): Observable<{ "Field1": string, "Field2": string }[]> {
    const apiURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    return this.http.get(apiURL) 
        .map(res => res.json().MyValues)
  }`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski same than https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users but with the content under "MyValues" node.

Comment: Dude please provide the expected result and the current result you are getting, so that we can help you better.

Comment: @Kris-I i don't understand - provide exact result you wanna get (in link you provided we have array at top level...

Comment: I change the post I hope will be clearer now.

Comment: @Kris-I you still not provide example output (json?) you wanna get

Comment: Updated  as I said yesterday split each node of the backend result in two variables with json format.

Comment: @Kris-I - what do you mean by "In one variable.. .second variable" ? The http.get...map reurns ONE object. Update you post and show in which way you call search() function to get data

Comment: @Kris-I  -second thing - you provide BROKEN/INVALID json as example output (!!!) (do you mean array of obiects or something?) please repair it (and check in https://jsonlint.com/ ).

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Updated.

Comment: @Kris-I what do you mean by "In one variable.. .second variable" ? The http.get...map reurns ONE object. Update you post and show in which way you call search() function to get data

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski are you kidding ? I know the http get return one object, in this one object there are 2 part "FirstResponse" and "SecondResponse" (or firstResponse and secondResponse) I need each part in 2 variables. But gave up I will find the solution somewhere else.

Comment: @Kris-I no i seriously asking - how do you call search() function? Do you wanna have this two variables inside this search function (inside `map` ? ) or you wanna this two variables in some other place (after calling search()) - where exactly (?) - precise it  (I update also my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new file which exports the model class and then assign it to the returning Observable type. Something like:

new model.ts file

```
class FieldModel {
    Field1: string;
    Field1: string;
}
export class valuesModel {
    MyValues: Array<FieldModel>;
}
```

on the service.ts

```
import { valuesModel } from 'model';

search(): Observable<valuesModel> {
    let apiURL = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`;
    return this.http.get(apiURL) 
        .map(res => res.json())
}
```

Comment: The problem is not with jsonplaceholder but with the result of my WebApi

Comment: @Kris-I What are you getting as response? Can you a sample?

Comment: @PrateekGogia I just want a Json with the values under 'MyValue' node

Answer (score 0):

I don't crealry understan what you wanna get because you not provide example result,

however try this - change line:

```
.map(res => res.json())
```

to

```
.map(res => res.json().MyValues )
```

using this you will get at the top level similar array like in link you provided in comment below you question:  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

**UPDATE** (after question update 9.10.2018)

Currently `.map(res => res.json())` returns object that has two fields (variables) "FirstResponse" and "SecondResponse". You can have acces to it by for example (I write code from head):

```
public async loadData() 
{
   let data  = await this.yourService.search().toPromise();

   let firstVariable = data.FirstResponse;
   let secondVariable = data.SecondResponse;     

   ...
}
```

So as you describe in your question/comments in loadData() you get result in two variables as you want.

Or alternative answer - if you wanna do this inside search() then you can do that in such way for example:

```
search(): Observable<any> {
  let apiURL = `......`;
  return this.http.get(apiURL) 
      .map( (res) => { 
          let data = res.json();
          return {
              firstVariable: data.FirstResponse,
              secondVariable: data.SecondResponse,  
          }
      })
}
```

Comment: @Kris-I you still not provide example output (json?) you wanna get

Comment: @Kris-I I update my answer considering your comment and question update.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this approach, use 
`import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

```
public search(){
let apiURL = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`;
return this.http.get(apiURL) 
  .map((res: Response)=> return res.json();)
  .catch((error: Response) => {
        return Observable.throw('Something went wrong');   
  });
}
```

for this `search()` method you can subscribe from your component.

And if you want to map output into respected modal then please provide format of same.So that i can help

Comment: Never import rxjs/Rx

Comment: because it will import the whole of rxjs which will dramatically increase the size of your bundle... https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20349

Comment: But whatever solution I've provided to map output data.it's correct only. He has not mentioned about performance.